# SinonJS - Property Value before Stub Called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sinon

I am currently using [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) in for stubbing.
It is possible to stub and spy on methods, but not properties using the library from what I could see.

In the following example, would there be a way to check that `state.searchText` was set to `state.suggestion` *before* `submit` is called?

```
   // currently using angular but applies equally to vanilla js
   $scope.searchSuggestion = function() {
        this.state.searchText = this.state.suggestion;
        this.submit();
    };
```

ideal testing code:

```
it('should set the searchText to be the suggestion', function(){
        // arrange
        sinon.stub(scope, 'submit');
        scope.state.searchText = 'old value';
        scope.state.suggestion = 'new value';
        // act
        scope.searchSuggestion();
        // assert
        expect(scope.submit.called).to.be(true) 
        // ~not sure how to see if searchText was set first
    });
```

Comment: Not sure why you want to use `sinon` with `angularjs`. AngularJS has been made to be a testable framework already and it make unit test quite easy. In your case at the end or just after you call `searchSuggestion()` add in the line  `expect(scope.state.searchText).toBe(scope.state.suggestion)` so that you can see if the `searchText` has new value or not. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, checking whether it has changed is not the issue. I want to test that it changed *before* `submit` is called. 

Sinon.js is a stubbing framework. It is extremely useful to use it in combination with AngularJS. Using it in this case allows be to check that  `submit` was called `expect(scope.submit.called).to.be(true) `

Answer (score 0):

I was just dealing with a similar issue, so answering despite this being a pretty old Q.

The approach that worked for me was replacing the function with one that does an assertion, so something like this:

```
it('should set the searchText to be the suggestion', function(){
    scope.state.searchText = 'old value';
    scope.state.suggestion = 'new value';

    scope.submit = function() {
      expect(whatever).to.equal(somethingElse);
    };

    scope.searchSuggestion();
});
```

This way when submit gets called, you can check preconditions using any assertion you want. Downside is you may have to add some extra code to handle restoring the original function back, and if the function never gets called, the test will pass without failure - so you may want to add a `done()` callback to it just in case.